# im faceing the errors in speech recognition

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
r=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone()as source:
    print(" speak :")
    audio=r.listen(source)
    try:
        output=r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(" you said :".format(output))
    except:
       print(" i cont recognize what u said place spaek clear")
```

ERRORS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/codes/speechreg.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone()as source:
  File "C:\Users\bjman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 141, in __enter__
    input=True,  # stream is an input stream
  File "C:\Users\bjman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bjman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable access to your microphone? Try enabling microphone using this [guid](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027981/windows-10-how-to-set-up-and-test-microphones).
I think your code didn't print the output. try to change the following line,

```
print(" you said :{}".format(output))
```

And this code will perform as your desire.You can try it as well!

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
r=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone()as source:
    print(" speak :")
    audio=r.listen(source)
    try:
        value = r.recognize_google(audio)

        if str is bytes: 
            result = u"{}".format(value).encode("utf-8")

        else: 
            result = "{}".format(value)

        with open("outputs.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(result)
        print(result)
    except:
       print(" i cont recognize what u said place spaek clear")
```

Comment: I use and try your code also @Ransaka Ravihara but I'm having same error know also